# AngularJS - Unit test with header response

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

My backend retrieves me a `'x-token'` when a user log in successfully on my web. On my frontend I do a simple validation, getting this token and setting: `$rootScope.authenticated = true;` if the token is not present on the header response for any reason my frontend sets: `$rootScope.authenticated = false;`

**My Controller**

```
signinService
    .signin(datafromForm)
    .then(function (data) {
        if ( $myTokenManager.save(data.headers('x-token')) ) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        } else {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            // Unit test is sent it here :(
        }

    });
```

This is working perfect, now I need to do a unit test for this method, but my test is not generating or setting the header response properly. What am I doing wrong on my test?

```
describe('Testing controllers', function() {

    describe('MyController unit test', function() {

        var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController, authRequestHandler, datafromForm;

        beforeEach(module('myapp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {

            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

            authRequestHandler = $httpBackend
                                    .when(
                                        'POST',
                                        'http://mywebapp:8080/loginuser',
                                        {"username":"admin", "password":"admin"}
                                    ).respond({'x-token': 'XXX'});

            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

            createController = function() {
                return $controller('MyController', {'$scope' : $rootScope});
            }
        }));

        //
        afterEach(function() {
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });

        //
        it('should authentication user', function() {

            var controller = createController();

            //
            $rootScope.username = "admin";
            $rootScope.password = "admin";

            datafromForm = {
                username: $rootScope.username,
                password: $rootScope.password
            };

            $httpBackend.expectPOST(
                'http://mywebapp:8080/loginuser',
                {"username":"admin", "password":"admin"}
            ).respond(
                200, 
                {'x-token': 'XXX'}
            );

            $rootScope.login(formData);
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect($rootScope.authenticated).toBe(true); // This is getting false :(
        });





    });

});
```

I'm following [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) example on angular documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documented signature of the `respond()` function is

```
function([status,] data[, headers, statusText])
```

In your first `respond()`, you only pass data, and no header:

```
respond({'x-token': 'XXX'});
```

In your second `respond()`, you only pass status and data, and still no header:

```
respond(
    200, 
    {'x-token': 'XXX'}
);
```

Comment: @razorblade desperately needing your quizzes :-) Thanks.